# Writing each line from Textarea in a single document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, textarea, mongoid, nested-forms

I want write mulitple lines from a textarea to a mongodb database:

1. First Line
2. Second Line
3. Third Line

etc.

Each line should be written in a single document.

So what I first figured out that I might use the gsub-function for separating the lines and after that I could write them with an each do - loop to the database.

And this point I got stuck.

Thanks in Advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arthur's solution is correct if what you want is to put each line as sub-document of a single document.

If you really want multiple documents, then this may be the solution if it uses rails.

```
inputString=params["textareainput"]
lines=inputString.split("\n")
lines.each do |l|
    Book.create(:content => l)
end
```

The code is placed in the controller (if you use MVC, probably in Rails framework)

Answer (score 0):

So if you wanna have the lines split in your database, what would do, is something like this:

```
class Book
  field :lines, type: Array

  def text=(t)
    doc = []
    t.each_line { |l| dpc << l }
    self.lines = doc
  end
end
```